# [Unrealengine]way to sharing physic asset

Tags: c++, game-physics, unreal-engine4

i want to make wearable cloth system with unrealengine4 and its work quite nice, clothing system in 4.16 version of unrealengine is awesome!

now, i want to twist this things just a little bit.

im gonna scailing cheraacter skeleton, using bone controller. but cloths are still remaining same scale, and its gonna tight/loose if i scale up/down cheracter meshes.

i set clothing colision as character physics asset, and scale down my character via bone controller, but cloth's colision seems not scaled at all.

my guess is this : set colision as character physics asset is not just refrence it, its copying same asset. thats why i fail.

if its true, can i access set clothing colision in C++ codes? and not make copying asset, refrence character's physic asset?

or else... please give me some hint :D

sorry for bad english, and sorry for bad describe, im a student which is learn C and java for few month only

Thanks!

Comment: To be frank, unreal engine forum is the best place to ask this question. Unreal engine developers are more active there

Comment: @Asesh sigh, that forum also didnt reply my question at all. but thanks anyway!